# Delete an array from a multi-dimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array of this form:

```
array = [["http://domain.com/product.html", 10], ["http://domain.com/product.html", 150], ["http://domain.com/product.html", 500]]
```

I need to delete all arrays that have the last value smaller than 150.

I already tried the following, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
array.delete_if {|element| element.last < 150 }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your one should work.. What output you got ?

Comment: It somehow gives me the same array, it doesn't delete any element from it.

Comment: The code you've posted works as expected: http://codepad.org/CvR9Ykfr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it this way:

```
array.reject!{|x| x if x.last < 150}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this post,, It is another way to solve this.. Do you know why `#delete_if` didn't work in OP's example, which I am quite sure should work

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work, it just gives me the same multi-dimensional array, unchanged.

Comment: Perhaps the OP didn't refer to the return value, but referred to `array` again. That is the point of this answer.

Comment: I don't know why this answers has been entertained, which has not been asked.. OP didn't ask how to do it, while OP asked *why not working*

Comment: @user3493101 Although this answer misleading, correct way to write is `array.reject!{|x| x.last < 150}`. If you like it, teach yourself, this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
array.map{|f| f if f.last < 150}.compact
```

I don't know if it is better or not than `Akarsh`, just another solution that I would have used.
Anyways, your solution works, `user3493101`, but if it doesn't, you can still use that.